# SQLite removing a set where {A,B} and {B,A}

Tags: sql, select, tuples, set

Can someone please help me on a sql query where there's a table such as

```
Col A | Col B
-------------
A       B
C       D
E       F
B       A
```

how do I remove {B, A} or select {B, A}

The question is:

```
If two students A and B are friends, and A likes B but not vice-versa,
remove the Likes tuple.
```

I have figured out the table where A and B are friends and A likes B, but I don't know how to remove the B likes A tuple

I have

```
select friend.id1, friend.id2
from friend, likes
where friend.id1 = likes.id1 and friend.id2 = likes.id2
```

Comment: the table structure you have given is of like table or freinds table , if it of like table then as per your question `A likes B but not vice-versa,` `A likes B but not B likes A` then `{B,A}` should not be removed but `{C,D},{E,F}`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this homework assignment before...

```
DELETE FROM Likes
WHERE ID1 IN (SELECT L.ID1
                       FROM Friend F,Likes L
                       WHERE F.ID1 = L.ID1 AND F.ID2 = L.ID2
                       AND F.ID1 NOT IN (SELECT ID2 
                                         FROM Likes
                                         WHERE ID1=L.ID2 AND ID2=L.ID1))
```

Try to figure these out on your own -- or if you can't, try searching Google.

Comment: Thank you. It took awhile, but I got the logic. A tip for others, highlight the row, and col B. In the row for col A; match where col B is the same. That is where the "not in" clause is doing.

Comment: Hi. I came up with a similar query, but in my opinion, it deletes too much tuples, because we are restricting just id1. I'm struggling to delete based on two columns values, but so far no success. What do you think?

Comment: I wanted to write the query like this: https://bitbucket.org/sanjayts/dbclass/src/680caa177fd09dfa118c11bf96b990c76a8d69ca/sql/exercise-quiz/social-network-modification-solution.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM friends f1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM friends f2
    WHERE f2.a = f1.b AND f2.b = f1.a
    );
```

NOTE: this will probably **not** work in mysql, because it does not allow the target table to be referenced in a subquery.